# how to find out how this log file is created in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket in s3 there is a folder named "s3-logs" there is a lot of logs files are created and still creating how can i know this how it is created and which service are log are store in my s3 bucket
if i show you the inside the log file is something like below

```
1e644f4814107b8d443c5cgbv2cac2b326f268dbb79aba90e2fefaec79c08b02fbb rohanjangid [
16/Jan/2022:02:44:31 +0000] - svc:s3.amazonaws.com A4BCMAHA71ZFN9E4 REST.PUT.OBJECT s3-logs/2022-01-16-02-44-31-3647796663AC4125 "PUT /rohanjangid/s3-logs/2022-01-16-02-44-31-3647796663AC4125 HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 944 77 48 "-" "-" - sau9smP0pMvLuQmf0f7f2aTEMPEkCjYPkXGYlkra2B/CJdwwCJ5/nBaeeg= SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2 -
```

note: server access logging is off on bucket

Comment: It looks like an S3 bucket access log. Look at all of your S3 buckets and see which have logging configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those sound like S3 server access logs.

To check this, go through the following steps:

- go to the S3 dashboard,
- click on the bucket name,
- click on the "Properties" tab, scroll down to the "Server access logging" section,
- check if "server access logging" is listed as Enabled.
- If it is enabled, click on the "Edit" button and check if "Target bucket" matches the log path you're seeing filled.
- If the target bucket is the one getting filled, just empty the bucket.